# Change the statistics from percentages to number of events

Tags: python

I found an interesting library and I would like to make changes in this code. I would like to see the number of events divided by the sum of events (like 5/52 etc.), under percentages. How can I add it?

link to the library:
https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plots/plot_heatmap_positional.html

This part of the code displays data but I don't know how to change it:

```
 total = np.array([bs['statistic'].sum() for bs in bin_statistic]).sum()
    # replace raw counts with percentages and add percentage sign (note immutable named tuple so used _replace)
    for bs in bin_statistic:
        bs['statistic'] = (pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic'] / total)
                           .applymap(lambda x: '{:.0%}'.format(x))
                           .values)
```

[image]

Comment: `(pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic']).applymap(lambda x: '{0}/{1}'.format(x, total)).values)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks, it's works. But now this is showing me some strange numbers (the photo will send in the post above).

Comment: That's because those numbers are probably floats. You can add `:.0f` to the format specifier to tell it to write zero decimal places. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown replaces the `"statistic"` column of the dataframe with a new column, which contains the percentages.

```
bs['statistic'] = (pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic'] / total)
                           .applymap(lambda x: '{:.0%}'.format(x))
                           .values)
```

Let's split it into a couplelines to make it easier to understand:

```
# divide the statistic column by the total
percentages = pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic'] / total) 

# format percentages using the specifier {:.0%}
bs['statistic'] = (percentages.applymap(lambda x: '{:.0%}'.format(x)).values)
```

Once the percentages are calculated, the `str.format()` function is used to format each value as a percentage with zero decimal places (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

So all you need to do is change what is being formatted, and how it is formatted.

```
outputval = pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic']) # it might not be necessary to cast to pd.DataFrame
bs['statistic'] = (outputval.applymap(lambda x: '{0:.0f}/{1:.0f}'.format(x, total)).values)
```

Or in one line:

```
bs['statistic'] = (pd.DataFrame(bs['statistic']).applymap(lambda x: '{0:.0f}/{1:.0f}'.format(x, total)).values)
```

Comment: I wrote it bad. I don't mean the format. For example, There are 3 points in one of the sectors, it counts as 2 and the sum of these points is 4 but should be 11.

Comment: Sorry. It works, my fault. Thanks for help. I made a big mistake and didn't see him.